# How to achieve method injection into an action method in ASP.Net MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dependency-injection

```
public ActionResult Hello(IEmployee employee)
    {
        employee.Name = "ABC";
        employee.Company = "XYZ";
        employee.SSN = "****";
        return View(employee);
    }
```

I am passing the employee object by abstraction.

Comment: Why do you want to inject dependencies into action method opposed to injecting them in the controller's constructor?

Comment: You cant. Its an `ActionResult` method and the first step in the binding process is that the `DefaultModelBinder` will try to initialize an instance of your model, which fails because its an interface. In any case you cant post back an interface for the same reason so it hard to understand what your trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you have multiple implementations of `IEmployee`? Which implementation of `IEmployee ` should the binder use?

Comment: Perhaps he has multiple dependencies, each dependency needed by one action method ...? Using constructor injection would lead to "overinjection", cause only one dependency is needed for example.